# getting text from text file into an array

Tags: c#

I have a text file and contain text below:

```
Contact Name        |       Contact Number

Muhammad Hassan Ali Khan|       123456
Danish Abdul Ghani      |       165484
Adeel Siddiqui          |       865697
Muhammad Faisal Bilal   |       569745
Arslan                  |       145236
```

and I want to dispaly it as it is in the gridview and i am using the following code: for checking that i am right working for getting text from a file.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string line = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("c:\\Contacts.txt");
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] arr = line.Split('\t\t|\t\t');
            }
        }
```

But at this line "string[] arr = line.Split('\t\t|\t\t');" error occur:

```
Error: Too many characters in character literal
```

How to remove this error. Kindly suggest me. waiting for reply. Thanks

Comment: The apostrophe in `Split('')  indicates a type of `Char`, which can only hold a single character.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
 string line = "";
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("c:\\Contacts.txt");
 while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
      string[] arr = line.Split('|');
      arr = arr.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: This is the only answer that will actually work properly as the original solution of \t\t|\t\t is not correct anyway based on the provided source data.

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
string[] arr = line.Split(new string[] { "\t\t|\t\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Edit: `'` encapsulates a character, `"` is for strings.

Comment: ojlovecd: your line of code is working but it gets only the first line Contact Name        |       Contact Number and I want to get all above text,

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an array of characters to the [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. The characters from array will be used as separators for splitting.

As the method Split() has a keyword *params* in its signature, you can omit the direct creation of the array and just pass characters separated by comma.

The examples:

```
string[] arr = line.Split('|');
string[] another = line.Split('|','-',':','!');
```

It's well worth a note that one of the overloaded versions of Split() accepts a StringSplitOptions enumeration.

I would recommend you use it with StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries option. That will prevent appearing of empty elements in the result array. However, this version of the method does not have *params* keyword, so you do have to create the array.

```
var arr = mystring.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Because the String.Split() method actually has a signature with keyword 'params' e.g. String.Split(params char[] separator). So you can omit creation of the array, or even call it like mystring.Split('-',':','|');

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split on multiple characters, use `Regex`:

```
   line.Split(value, "'\t\t|\t\t'");
```